# How does antibody structure relate to function?

Tags: structural-biology, antibody, immune-system, protein-structure

I know that antibodies have 2 binding sites (as Y shape) so they can bind to 2 pathogens for agglutination. They have a hinge, heavy and light chains, constant and variable sections on these chains.

But how do these structures (and any obvious structures I have missed) relate to the function of antibodies?

Comment: This is a broad basic question that is well covered on numerous sites on the internet as well as standard texts that an be read on NCBI bookshelf. If you read the help on ["how to ask a good question"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will see that you are expected to explore such sources first. Try a search for [antibody structure and function](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=antibody+structure+and+function&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=DamhWu23Gq3P8AfAy4nwCA) or consult [Ch 33 of Berg et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21193/)